# Flutter find between 2 arrays if match

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 arrays like this

```
First = [{name: Lab, comments: adsd, id: 5},{name: Lab, comments: rerere, id: 1},{name: Lab, comments: rerere, id: 11}];

second =[{value: 1, label: cholesterol},{value: 5, label: sugar}{value: 10, label: sugar}];
```

I need to create new array in which if first array id and second array value is same then it will merge and show in new array.

For example i have 3 items in first array i need to match if id of my first array will find in second array so in third array data will be save.

Expected output is `final = [{value: 1, label: cholesterol, value: 1, label: cholesterol},{value: 5, label: sugar, name: Lab, comments: adsd, id: 5}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `where` and `map`methods for this.

Edited full code:

```
void main() {
  List first = [{"name": "Lab", "comments": "adsd", "id": 5},{"name": "Lab", "comments": "rerere", "id": 1},{"name": "Lab", "comments": "rerere", "id": 11}];

   List second =[{"value": 1, "label": "cholesterol"},{"value": 5, "label": "sugar"},{"value": 10, "label": "sugar"}];
  
  
  
  List result = second.where((s) {
    var value = s["value"];
    int index = first.indexWhere((f){
      return  f["id"] == value;
    });
    
    return index != -1;
  }).map((e){
    
    int index = findIndex(first,e);
    
    var data = first[index];
    
    return {
      "value": e["value"],
      "label": e["label"],
      "name": data["name"],
      "comments": data["comments"],
      "id": data["id"],
    };
  }).toList();
  
  print(result);
}

int findIndex(first,s) {
    var value = s["value"];
    int index = first.indexWhere((f){
      return  f["id"] == value;
    });
  return index;
}
```

What this code does is it iterates through element on the second list, and then searches for `id` that equals to `value` in first list, if it cannot find element index will be `-1`. So we are returning values of second where index not equal to `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have update my question i need to merge both array if they match and then show

Comment: I am updating my answer accordingly.